# How many ways can the number $10800$ be expressed as a product of two factors?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways can the number $10800$ be expressed as a product of two factors?

My attempt:

$10800 = 2^4 \times 3^3 \times 5^2$

So the number of ways is

$4\times 3\times 2  +1  = 25 $

Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly is meant with "factors" ? Does $1$ count as a "factor" ? Does the order matter ? The number of divisors is $5\cdot 4\cdot 3=60$

Comment: It means writing the number as a product of just two factors like $5\times 21600$@Peter

Comment: You did not address Peter's question. Does the order of the factors matter?  Is $36 \cdot 300$ different from $300 \cdot 36$?

Comment: Do not matter @ N.F.Taussing

Comment: To clarify, you are saying that the order of the factors does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, $10800 = 2^4 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2$.

Thus, each factor has the form $2^a3^b5^c$, where $0 \leq a \leq 4$, $0 \leq b \leq 3$, and $0 \leq c \leq 2$.  If the two factors are $2^{a_1}3^{b_1}5^{c_1}$ and $2^{a_2}3^{b_2}5^{c_2}$, then
\begin{align*}
a_1 + a_2 & = 4 \tag{1}\\
b_1 + b_2 & = 3 \tag{2}\\
c_1 + c_2 & = 2 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 1 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $5$ solutions, namely $(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4)$.  Similarly, equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $4$ solutions, and equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $3$ solutions.  Thus, there are $$5 \cdot  4 \cdot 3 = 60$$ ordered pairs of factors.  Since $10,800$ is not a perfect square, each pair contains two distinct factors.  Thus, we have counted each unordered pair of factors twice, so there are
$$\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{2} = 30$$
unordered pairs of factors of $10,800$.

Comment: Is there a formula to solve such questions ? @N.F.Tasussig

Comment: For two factors, if the number factors as $n = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then there are $(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1)$ ordered pairs of factors.  If $n$ is not a perfect square, then the number of unordered pairs of factors is $\frac{(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1)}{2}$.  If $n$ is a perfect square, then the number of unordered pairs of factors is $\frac{(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1) - 1}{2} + 1 = \frac{(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1) + 1}{2}$  since we would count the product $\sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{n}$ one half time if we simply divided by $2$.

Comment: I should add that choosing the exponents for the first factor determines the exponents for the second factor.  If $a_i$ is the exponent of $p_i$ in the factorization of $n$ and the first factor has exponent $b_i$, then the other factor must have exponent $a_i - b_i$.  Note that the exponent of the first factor can vary from $0$ to $a_i$, giving $a_i + 1$ possible choices for the exponent of $p_i$.